# Not able to add value to `body` tag through page css file

Tags: sass, angular5

In my angular app, i am adding a class name to body like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.updatePageClass('page-quoteCart');
  }
```

on the page.css I am writing a class like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px)  and (max-width: 620px) {

    .page-quoteCart{
        border:2px solid red; //but not added
    }

}
```

But not getting the output. If I write the same in style.css in `assets` folder that works. what is the issue here?

how to write the css according to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your html.
It will solve your issue.

for example after you update your `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` - your component file will look like this:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'xxxxx',
  templateUrl: 'xxxxx.html',
  styleUrls: ['xxxx.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```